Facing pyodbc.InterfaceError When Connecting to SQL Server Using Python 3.10
I am currently encountering an issue with a Python script that connects to a SQL Server database using pyodbc. This script was functioning correctly under Python 3.7.3, but since upgrading to Python 3.10, I am facing an interface error. Despite setting environment variables and specifying driver details in my connection string, the problem persists. I would be very grateful for any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue.
Environment:
Previous Python version: 3.7.3 (no issues)
Current Python version: 3.10
OS: Unix-based system
Code
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

with open('in.txt', "r") as file:
    readline=file.read().split("\n")
    pwd_in = readline[0]

def connect_to_sc():
    seoud_connection = pyodbc.connect(
        Driver = 'SQLServer-Driver',
        Server = 'SKL2SQ6.org,2893',
        Database = 'Seroud',
        User = 'JKL_User',
        Password = pwd_in,
        Trusted_Connection = 'No'
    )
    return seoud_connection

Environment Configuration:
source /sys_apps_01/python/python310/profile/env.sh
export ODBCINI=/sys_apps_01/python/python310/odbc/odbc.ini
export ODBCINSTINI=/sys_apps_01/python/python310/odbc/odbcinst.ini
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/sys_apps_01/python/python310/sqlserver/msodbcsql17/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
python3.10 main.py

Error Message:
File location using os.getcwd(): /cus_intel_01/suim/kls/emailmanual
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cus_intel_01/suim/kls/emailmanual/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    exec(open(path).read())
  File "<string>", line 68, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 14, in connect_to_sc
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Any help in diagnosing and resolving this error would be deeply appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance!

"SQLServer-Driver" isn't a driver I've ever heard of; why not use the latest official ODBC driver?

At a command prompt, run odbcinst -j. The DRIVERS... line shows the location of your odbcinst.ini file. Please [edit] your question to show the [SQLServer-Driver] section from that file.

You should know which driver you need to connect.
Need to connect with the latest driver available and specify that driver name in connection.
Can check your drivers by:
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())

You will get a list of all the drivers available for you.
I get this output:
['SQL Server',
 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
 'HDBODBC',
 'Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver',
 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']

So, I use ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server for my connection:
Your code with me becomes:
seoud_connection = pyodbc.connect(
        Driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        Server = 'SKL2SQ6.org,2893',
        Database = 'Seroud',
        User = 'JKL_User',
        Password = pwd_in,
        Trusted_Connection = 'No'
    )


When I do import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())   I am getting
['ODBC Drivers', 'HiveODBC-Driver', 'ImpalaODBC-Driver', 'OracleODBC-12c', 'NetezzaSQL', 'SQLServer-Driver']

Please see which one is best for you. There can be other reasons for your error as well.
